# html5 dropdownlist using FindByValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

my dropdownlist HTML5

```
<select runat="server" id="ddlStateLegalRes" name="ddlStateLegalRes"></select>
```

On my page load I am binding my dropdownlist to a list collection with a list of states

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    List<StateList> states = ops.getStates();
                    ddlStateLegalRes.DataTextField = "StateRegionName";
                    ddlStateLegalRes.DataValueField = "StateRegionCode";
                    ddlStateLegalRes.DataSource = states;
                    ddlStateLegalRes.DataBind();

    GetAllInfo();
```

EDITED****
 There is something weird going on and I cant seem to pinpoint it when I debug. For some strange reason this was working as it is supposed to but then started throwing this Error  "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"

I know the list collection is getting the correct values and I also know that "STATEOFLEGALRESIDENCE" is being returned by my stored procedure with the value "FL" and the spelling is correct.

```
"""Inside my GetAllInfo() method
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
          ddlStateLegalRes.Items.FindByValue(sdr["STATEOFLEGALRESIDENCE"].ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
```

What i suspect is that it is trying to set my dropdownlist with a value before the code is actually done binding my dropdownlist with values. So i tried to move the GetAllInfo() method into the Page_LoadComplete event and still the same error so now I am at a lost please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the value that is returned from the reader does not match exactly or it is missing from the list items.

I would put a break point at the point & check that these values match:

Try this but replace 0 with the value of the item.

```
 ddlStateLegalRes.Items[0] == sdr["STATEOFLEGALRESIDENCE"].ToString());
```

It sounds like a case or white space triong issue.

Comment: I would also refactor the above by moving the populate into it's own method i.e. BindStates method which encapsulates the functionality.

Comment: Thanks hutch yes i tried this and it still returns the same error also I have refactored per your suggestion to make the code cleaner. Any other ideas?

Comment: when i debug I see the correct value being return by my reader seems like it is throwing an exception once it trys to set the dropdownlist to that value

Comment: I also see the list collection is returning and the dropdownlist is binding all the states as it is supposed to if i comment out the code that is simply telling the dropdown which state to display. This is so frustrating seems like this should be working and i cant see what I am doing wrong

Comment: Please see my other comments, give that a go. :)

Comment: wow you will laugh when i tell you what it was. Your suggestion help lead me to the source of the problem. In my db I set the datatype to char(3) and i was trying to match FL but the database stored it with an FL(space) so i changed it to varchar(3) and all is well thanks for sticking with me through this appreciate all your help

Comment: Nice one. No probs. Good luck with the rest.